# How to write constant value in parquet file using scala?

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, parquet

I'm using spark .I want to save value 2.484 which repeated 13849 times in parquet file instead of console.[save values in parquet file instead of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ad4.png)

```
implicit class Rep(n: Int) {
def times[A](f: => A): Seq[A] = { 1 to n map(_ => f) } 
}
val myHis= 13849.times { println("2.4848911616270923")}
```

this code which repeate value 2.484.
How to save it in parquet file?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._


val myHis:Dataset[String] = ???

val path:String = ??? //the path you want

myHis.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path)
```

Try this

Comment: there is error in val myHis:Dataset[???] = ??? give me
']' expected but ';' and identifier expected but integer literal found.

Comment: Ok so the ??? is used when it is not implemented, so you need to change the ??? for the things you want

Comment: You basically just need to convert your Seq[String] into a Dataset[String] with the .toDS and it should work

Comment: certainly .import org.apache.spark.sql._
val myHis:Dataset[13849] = 2.4848911616270923

val path:String = "file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/out"

myHis.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/out")

Comment: val myHis= 13849.times { "2.4848911616270923"}
val ds = myHis.toDs

Comment: Have you used Spark before? You need to have configurations the imports there and so on

Comment: values appear in console are Double not string.

Comment: "2.4848911616270923" is a String, if you want a Double then it is 2.4848911616270923, but then it is a Dataset[Double]

Comment: error is value toDs is not a member of Seq[Double] and value write is not a member of Seq[Double].

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-datasets.html